# How to select among overlapping linear features by create date?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy

I have a table which has overlapping linear data; for example:

```
A----------C and B---------C.
```

Of these two records I would only like to return the record with the latest create date; in other words, the record created last.  How do I set up up my Search Cursor to produce the desired result?  Really what I'm attempting to perform is dynamic segmentation depending on the create date.  My end result can be `A---B` then `B---C` or if the create date of the first record (which is from `A-----C`) is newer than the create date for `B-----C`, I should just return record `A----C`.

Comment: Do your rows have an autonumber ID schema? If so, you could just get the row with the larger autonumber ID.

Comment: @Conor I'm not sure I understand your soluction

Comment: @Conor is referring to the OID field. It is an automatically created, sequential field. Newer items will have higher OIDs because they were created later.

Comment: Note the [different behavior of OBJECTID, FID, and OID fields for shapefiles and gdb](http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/37480): If a record from a shapefile is deleted, the FIDs are renumbered!

Comment: If A-C is newer you return A-C, if B-C is newer you return B-C. When would you return A-B then B-C? When the dates are equal?

Comment: The "Date/Time" metadata of a feature is not stored upon feature creation, or if it is, it is not exposed for you to retrieve it programatically (IRow and IFeature do not have these properties in ArcObjects documentation). You can use a Geodatabase and the OID field to store and retrieve this data or you can programatically create Date/Time fields in your attribute table for each new created feature.

Comment: @Hornbydd I'm attempting to dynamically segment a dataset. If for example a linear feature such as coating on a pipeline was installed 1/1/1998 which went from A-----C but on 1/1/2007 a new coating was installed from B---C without removing the prior coating you would want to retrieve the following coating: From A---B install date 1/1/1998 and from B----C 1/1/2007. The end result is a dynamic segmentation of my coating table without overlaps.

Comment: It sounds like from your description above that you have date attributes in your table already - if that is the case then you you can simply formulate a select statement like in my answer below that grabs the earliest date instead of the smallest OBJECTID #.

Comment: @Conor Thanks for helping me out, I'll try your suggestion once my kids go to sleep.

Answer (score 1):

**For a geodatabase**: (I have not tested this code, there may be some syntax errors, especially in the SQL statements)

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy

# Set the workspace
env.workspace = "c:/yourgeodatabasename.gdb"

# Make a layer from the feature class
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("yourfeatureclassname", "lyr") 

# Select the multiple rows from which you want to grab the ealier date
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", 'SQL_where_clause_with_original_selection_criteria')

# Within selected features, further select the row that was created earliest (the row with the lowest OID)

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("lyr", "SUBSET_SELECTION", '[OBJECTID] in (SELECT min( [OBJECTID] ) FROM table_name)')
```

For a shapefile, you will need to create date/time fields and store the date/time in them every time that a new feature is created.

Comment: It looks like your criteria for selecting these features is overlapping polygons. In that case, instead of using arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management() method, you may want to use arcpy.SelectLayerByALocation_management() instead for the first select.